# Category of modules

Tags: category-theory, modules

For given a ring $R$, we can define the category of left $R$-modules. In fact, objects are all left $R$-modules and morphisms are $R$-module homomorphisms. NOw my question is:

If we do not fix $R$, then how are able to define a category containing all left modules. In other words, our objects are all pairs $(M,R)$ where $M$ is an abelian group and $R$ is a ring and moreover $R$ acts on $M$ i.e $M$ is a left $R$-module. But for defining morphisms, I am not sure.

Comment: The issue is how the varying types of rings can interact and such

Comment: You also might be interested of the (pseudo) double category structure where objects are rings, vertical morphisms are *bimodules* between rings and horizontal morphisms are ring homomorphisms.
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+category

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This category appears in a paper by Maurice Auslander, *Representation Theory of Artin Algebras I*, Communications in Algebra, Volume 1, Issue 3, 1974, 177-268.

In his definition, objects of this category are pairs $(R,M)$, where $R$ is a ring and $M$ is an $R$-module.  A morphism from $(R_1, M_1)$ to $(R_2, M_2)$ is a pair $(f,g)$, where $f:R_1\to R_2$ is a morphism of rings, and $g:M_1\to M_2$ is a morphism of abelian groups such that for all $r\in R_1$ and $x\in M_1$, we have $g(rx)=f(r)g(x)$.

Comment: Got a good link to the article?

Comment: @ZelosMalum I haven't found one that isn't behind a paywall, I'm afraid.  This is partly why I've included the definition of the category.

Comment: Can't even find it through my universities >X

Comment: @ZelosMalum It does appear in the *Selected Works of Maurice Auslander, Part 1*, though.

Comment: I found it in his book of the same name! :D

Comment: I was looking for exactly this but it wasn't easy to find. How common is the use of this category among mathematicians?